# How to start using my new installation of JabbR on AppHarbor?

Tags: asp.net, signalr, appharbor, janrain, jabbr

Question to all the JabbR/SignalR/AppHarbor/Janrain/ASP.NET integration experts out there:

- I **successfully** forked JabbR from GitHub and cloned into my repo!!!
- I also **successfully** deployed to a new AppHarbor application in the Beta environment in order to enjoy WebSocket support!!!
- I also **successfully** set up JanRain's engage service for authentication for my application.
- I also **happily** saw my application start up on the public domain (http://jabbr-14.apphb.com/) and **successfully** created my first account and got authenticated.

NOW, I just CAN't post, create, broadcast, etc., or —for that matter— do anything useful in my chat!!!

How do I start using this thing?!?!

**Basically this is how my app looks in the browser, but I just can't get it to do anything!!!**

[image]

Comment: did you "/create room"? You can see all the commands (which can be entered into the text box) by clicking the "?" button in the upper right.

Comment: u deserve a coffee... thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @halter73 mentioned, it was only that commands have to preceded with '/'.